# Bootstrap 3 row and col order on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following structure

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    box 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    box 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            box 3 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a possibility with bootstrap to easily show the following order on small screens?

|box1|

|box3|

|box2|

I could not figure out how to swap rows in this manner. Thank you

Comment: are you using bootstrap3 or 4?

Comment: i use Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the box column in other row. you can have all the box column in same row. You can achieve the column order in bootstrap using `col-sm-push-*` or `col-sm-pull-*` utility.

Check demo [here](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/gWqydy)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column 1</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column 3</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Column 2</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks very neat :)